# Is a limit of a sequence of distribution functions is necessarily a distribution function

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, examples-counterexamples

I got a question: "is a limit of a sequence of distribution functions is necessarily a distribution function". My answer is NO. I have a counterexample:

$F_n(x)=0$ if $x<n$ and $1$ otherwise. It is a distribution function for any $n$. Now $\lim_{n\to \infty}F_n(x)=0$ for all $x \in R$. The resulting function $F(x)=0$ for all $x \in R$ is not a distribution function anymore.

Would you agree with the counterexample? Do you know other counterexamples?

Comment: Yes. Or F_n = CDF of uniform distribution on (0,n). Or F_n = CDF of uniform distribution on (-n,0). Or F_n = CDF of uniform distribution on (-n,n). (These three examples have distinct features.)

Comment: OK, I see, the CDF of a uniform distribution on $(0,n)$ limits to $F=0$, the CDF of a uniform distribution on $(-n,0)$ limits to $F=1$ and the CDF of uniform distribution on $(-n,n)$ limits $1/2$, right?

Comment: Exactly. And none of these limits is a CDF, as you surely noted.